# iphone: how to block touches while showing some UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

my current scenario is this -> i am showing a view controller that has a button. when i click that button a small view opens. now what i want. when that view is shown i don't want user to touch below that ( even in navigation bar's back button ). the same thing which UIAlertView does. how i can achieve that thing with my custom view ??

Please suggest.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate if you accept it. If not, please provide further information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cover the current view with a different `UIView` which would take the touches and stop them.
Here's some code to overlay a `UIView` which is black (and slightly transparent) to block touches.

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; 
blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blackView.alpha = 0.8f;
[self.view addSubview:blackView];
```

**UPDATE**

To disable the back button, try using the following.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: but this will not stop touches on navigation controller. the back button will still work. i want that the back button on navigation controller should not work. how to do that ?